# How do I get song names and artists from mp3 files in a dir?

Tags: data-recovery, file-metadata, flac

I have a recovered dir with mp3 and flac files. The names were lost. So all I got is a mess of around 30,000 files iwth names like f30818304.flac

I played some and see that the tags in the files are intact. 
But the thing is, most of it I probably don't need. I just want to see if there's any rarities in those files. So what I need is a way to massively write the tags to a file. Like "Artist - Song", one per line would be enough.

Anyone know of a way to do this ? command line preferably.

Comment: For the record, FLAC files are not MP3 files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [eyeD3](https://github.com/nicfit/eyeD3/) ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24233920/4970442)):

```bash
sudo apt install eyed3

find /usr/audio/incoming -name '*.mp3' -exec eyeD3 -t 'New Title' '{}' \; -exec mv '{}' /usr/audio/complete \;
```

> `-t STRING`, `--title=STRING` Set the track title.

Or for one folder [just](https://gist.github.com/williamrowell/4bfd05638190e05f6cbd)

```bash
eyeD3 --rename '$artist - $album - $track:num - $title' *.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as I was waiting for an answer I started the slow process of listen to the files and discard the ones I didn't need anymore. So I put 200 in a dir and open in VLC. It open the list almost instantly and showed all the tags in the format I need. Then I tryied with 5000 files and it also made the great job of opening the file list with the tags almost instantly. So this is enough for me.

Good job VLC team. :)